# Bigger infinity than real number infinity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is there a bigger infinity than the infinity of cardinality of the real numbers $R$ ? i.e. is there a set to which real numbers can't be mapped one-one to ?

Comment: Yes, the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ for example, i.e. the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, often written as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @rlartiga that is simply false.

Comment: The set of all real functions has this size, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.  P(R) = {every subset of R}. 
There is a theorem that states that for every set g 
|p(g)|>|g|.
That means that for R:
|p(R)|=2^א < א=|R|
That also means that the real numbers cannot be mapped one-one to every subset of the real numbers R

Comment: You mean "set" and not "group".