# Can we count past $ \infty $?

Tags: infinity

Let's say, $ \infty $ is not the biggest number, in fact, there is something bigger, somewhere. We want to try and count past $ \infty $, because it is not really an ordinal one, but a definition of something uncountable or too big to even count.

What numbers are bigger than $ \infty $?

Comment: Well, when we are talking about ordinals, we call the smallest infinity $\omega$. So yes, you can count beyond $\omega$. For example, $\omega+1$, $2\omega$, $\omega^\omega$, etc.

Comment: See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743941/bigger-infinity-than-real-number-infinity).

Comment: Interesting (not too rigorous) youtube video that has the exact same title as your question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number

Comment: Yu can count, depending on the compactification you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\infty$ can't be the biggest number, because it isn't a number. It's just a symbol used in limits. Ok, you can consider compactifications of real or complex numbers, but that's certainly not what you had in  mind, because both are very far from "counting".

Comment: @RobArthan I have heard of ordinals, though it's been a long time (more than 50 years ago), and I know that $\infty$ is *not* an ordinal. $\omega$ is an ordinal, and you can count beyond it, naturally, as johnnyb explained in an answer that is better than my answer and your comment, together.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol $\infty$, as is currently used, simply means that the value is beyond the range supported by the real numbers.  It is not itself a number.  For instance, let's say that we only knew single-digit numbers.  We might have values, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and $\infty$, to represent a value that is outside the numbers we were familiar with.  That's what $\infty$ does.  You can't do any sort of arithmetic with it, because it isn't actually specific enough to be a value.  It's like when your calculator says "error".  You can't actually add two "error" values together, because they aren't really numbers.

However, there are number systems that are beyond the real numbers, and include larger values than are included in the real numbers.  Some of these systems include Cantor's transfinite numbers, the surreal numbers, and various hyperreal systems.

Hyperreal numbers are my favorite, as you can basically treat infinities as ordinary algebraic objects.  You simply have a symbol to represent some particular infinite value (since we can't actually count to infinity, I can't actually tell you *which* infinite value it represents), and then treat it algebraically.  I usually use $\omega$ for this.

So, in this system, $\omega + 1$ is a distinct number from $\omega$, as is $2\omega$ or $\omega^2$.  You can get infinitesimal numbers by dividing by $\omega$.  $\frac{1}{\omega}$ is closer to zero than any real number, but is still non-zero.  It's really easy to work with, and also simplifies many cases where real numbers have to have a lot of theorems to decide if the value can be contained by the real numbers.  In hyperreal numbers, all numbers essentially act as "finite" numbers even if they are infinite, so all of theorems around deciding if a value is finite or not are largely moot.

Answer (score 2):

Set ordinalities:

$0,1,2,...,\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,...,\omega^n,...,\omega^{\omega},...,\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{...}}}=\epsilon_0,...$

One might say it's hugely, vastly, mind-bogglingly big.